# Do I need infant cloth diaper covers with a cut-out for the umbilical cord?

Tags: newborn, cloth-diaper

We are in the process of purchasing our first round of cloth diapers for our soon to be born son.  We are planning to go with prefolds and covers and I have noticed that some of the companies sell [covers](http://www.sagediaper.com/home/dp1/image_options.html?myid=585) with a cut out for the umbilical cord.

Are these needed or just helpful?
Can you just fold down normal infant covers untill the cord falls off?
If they are needed can they be used even after the cord falls off?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) They aren't needed. Cloth folds very easily.
2) Yes, you can just fold down normal covers until the cord falls off.
3) Yes, they can be used even after the cord falls off.

Comment: @Swati - good comment, why not use it as an answer instead?

Comment: There was already an accepted answer, that's why :o

Comment: @Swati: If your answer is fantastic then the asker might accept yours instead. _And_ you get the chance to get upvotes from other readers! Be greedy :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, I can not see why these are necessary. You can affix a diaper in a way that does not cover the infant's belly button.

I have used cloth diapers with two children, and commend you for doing so. However, it is worth it to consider using disposables for the first few weeks. Especially the first days when the tarry black meconium is coming out, but also in the first few weeks when the baby poops every time he/she eats and the parents are just getting oriented, this can be helpful.

Comment: David's answer is good. As an additional note on the cleanup, you're going to be sick to death of cloth diapers if you have to wash them in the first several weeks. Newborns can pee and poop 10+ times a day normally, so unless that washer and dryer is running constantly, you simply can't keep up. Make life a little easier on yourselves during that adjustment period and transition from disposable to cloth slowly at around 1 month old.

Comment: Agreed, we never had trouble with either of our sons and we use disposables for both.